# Nginx proxy_cache

Tags: caching, nginx

I am trying to get nginx running as a cache proxy. The server is up and running properly - except it seems its not caching properly.

According to a scan with pingdom:

```
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify
an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

/layout/theme1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
/layout/theme1/css/bootstrap.min.css
/layout/theme1/css/font-awesome.css
/layout/theme1/css/pages/dashboard.css
/layout/theme1/css/style.css
/layout/theme1/css/theme.css
/layout/theme1/img/logo.png
/layout/theme1/js/bootstrap.js
/layout/theme1/js/chart.min.js
/layout/theme1/js/excanvas.min.js
/layout/theme1/js/jquery.js
```

My nginx proxy_cache settings are as follows:

Proxy Cache Path Settings:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/marketers.coop levels=1:2 keys_zone=marketers.coop:10m inactive=525600m max_size=5120m;
```

location settings:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://192.227.210.138:8080;
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 30d;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 30d;
    proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session $http_x_update;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|odt|ods|odp|odf|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|avi|mpeg|flv|html|htm)$ {
        proxy_pass      http://192.227.210.138:8080;
        proxy_cache    cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 30d;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 30d;
        root           /home/admin/web/marketers.coop/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/marketers.coop.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/marketers.coop.bytes bytes;
        expires        365d;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}
```

As can bee seen both css and js are set to be cached, yet neither the expire of 365 days nor the proxy cache valid for 30 days seems to be having any effect. What am I doing wrong?